# How can I read the 'sc.exe' start value of a service with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sc.exe

I can change the start value of a service with the command

```
sc config <service-name> start= <disabled, ..>
```

But how can I find out how the starting value is currently set?

Comment: Are you asking from inside the service? Or looking at started services from outside? Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Maybe [sc.exe query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-query) can help you? Also your question body doesn't actually mention C#, so are you sure your question is C#-related?

Comment: Maybe you are asking about `sc qc <service-name>`.

Comment: Hello together
After some reflection, I came to the idea, that it would be enought, to know if the service is running. So, is it possible, to find this out in C#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status